# Copying from private to local memory efficiently

Tags: opencl

I am trying to copy a chunk of data from private to local memory efficiently. Each work item needs to copy 3 bytes to local memory, so currently i do:

```
__kernel void apply(__local uchar* lmem) {
    int offset = ...;
    uchar data[3] = {1,2,3}; // just an example, is passed as an argument in fact
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        lmem[offset+j] = data[j];
    }    
}
```

However, i have the feeling that this could be done more efficiently (since i need to write 3 consecutive bytes). Therefore, i tried using `memcpy`:

```
__kernel void apply(__local uchar* lmem) {
    int offset = ...;
    uchar data[3] = {1,2,3};
    memcpy(&lmem[offset], data, 3);  
}
```

However, i get the following error message:
`error: passing '__local uchar *' (aka '__local unsigned char *') to parameter of type 'void *' changes address space of pointer`

I also tried using `async_work_group_copy`:

```
__kernel void apply(__local uchar* lmem) {
    int offset = ...;
    uchar data[3] = {1,2,3}
    event_t evt = async_work_group_copy((local uchar*) &lmem[offset], (uchar*) data, 3, 0);
    wait_group_events(3, &evt);
}
```

This results in the error:
`note: candidate function not viable: 2nd argument ('uchar *' (aka 'unsigned char *')) is in address space 0, but parameter must be in address space 16776960`

Is there a way to make each work item efficiently copy those 3 bytes from private to local memory, instead of having to copy those 3 bytes one by one?

---

EDIT: This is how i allocate the local memory and pass it to the kernel:

```
import pyopencl as cl
...
program = ...
lmem = cl.LocalMemory(needed_size)

applyKernel = program.apply
applyKernel.set_scalar_arg_dtypes([None]) # None because it is a buffer
applyKernel(queue, global_size, local_size, lmem)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vload3` to load from private array(or whatever memory specifier it is) and then use `vstore3` to store to local array or even global array

```
__kernel void test(__global unsigned char * data)
{
    int i=get_global_id(0);
    int l=get_local_id(0);
    unsigned char values[30]; 
    values[0]=1;
    values[1]=2;
    values[2]=3;
    __local unsigned char testLocalArray[3*256];
    vstore3(vload3(0,values),l,testLocalArray);
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    data[i*3]=testLocalArray[l*3];
    data[i*3+1]=testLocalArray[l*3+1];
    data[i*3+2]=testLocalArray[l*3+2];
}
```

this produces 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3 on the data array. But some hardware may not fully compatible with vector3 so it may actually load and store vector4 instead and give an error or wrong results unless you pad each block by 1 byte.

Since a vload or vstore is single instruction, it should use whatever hardware capability supported to do it in single instruction, if compiler is not already doing this automatically.

Its ISA code in R7-240 GPU:

```
s_mov_b32     m0, 0x00008000                              // 00000000: BEFC03FF 00008000
  s_buffer_load_dword  s0, s[8:11], 0x04                    // 00000008: C2000904
  s_buffer_load_dword  s1, s[8:11], 0x18                    // 0000000C: C2008918
  s_waitcnt     lgkmcnt(0)                                  // 00000010: BF8C007F
  s_min_u32     s0, s0, 0x0000ffff                          // 00000014: 8380FF00 0000FFFF
  s_mul_i32     s0, s16, s0                                 // 0000001C: 93000010
  v_mul_u32_u24  v1, v0, 3                                  // 00000020: D2160001 00010700
  s_add_u32     s0, s0, s1                                  // 00000028: 80000100
  v_mov_b32     v2, 1                                       // 0000002C: 7E040281
  s_buffer_load_dword  s1, s[12:15], 0x00                   // 00000030: C2008D00
  v_add_i32     v0, vcc, s0, v0                             // 00000034: 4A000000
  v_mov_b32     v3, 2                                       // 00000038: 7E060282
  v_mov_b32     v4, 3                                       // 0000003C: 7E080283
  v_mul_lo_i32  v0, v0, 3                                   // 00000040: D2D60000 00010700
  ds_write_b8   v1, v2                                      // 00000048: D8780000 00000201
  ds_write_b8   v1, v3 offset:1                             // 00000050: D8780001 00000301
  ds_write_b8   v1, v4 offset:2                             // 00000058: D8780002 00000401
  s_waitcnt     lgkmcnt(0)                                  // 00000060: BF8C007F
  v_add_i32     v0, vcc, s1, v0                             // 00000064: 4A000001
  s_barrier                                                 // 00000068: BF8A0000
  ds_read_u8    v2, v1                                      // 0000006C: D8E80000 02000001
  ds_read_u8    v3, v1 offset:1                             // 00000074: D8E80001 03000001
  ds_read_u8    v1, v1 offset:2                             // 0000007C: D8E80002 01000001
  s_waitcnt     lgkmcnt(2)                                  // 00000084: BF8C027F
  v_bfe_u32     v2, v2, 0, 8                                // 00000088: D2900002 02210102
  s_waitcnt     lgkmcnt(1)                                  // 00000090: BF8C017F
  v_bfe_u32     v3, v3, 0, 8                                // 00000094: D2900003 02210103
  s_waitcnt     lgkmcnt(0)                                  // 0000009C: BF8C007F
  v_bfe_u32     v1, v1, 0, 8                                // 000000A0: D2900001 02210101
  buffer_store_byte  v2, v0, s[4:7], 0 offen glc            // 000000A8: E0605000 80010200
  buffer_store_byte  v3, v0, s[4:7], 0 offen offset:1 glc   // 000000B0: E0605001 80010300
  buffer_store_byte  v1, v0, s[4:7], 0 offen offset:2 glc   // 000000B8: E0605002 80010100
```

looks like still 3 instructions behind the scene.

For RX550 GPU:

```
  //
  // &__OpenCL_test_kernel:
  //
  s_load_dword  s0, s[4:5], 0x04                        // 000000000100: C0020002 00000004
  s_mov_b32     m0, 0x00010000                          // 000000000108: BEFC00FF 00010000
  s_waitcnt     lgkmcnt(0)                              // 000000000110: BF8C007F
  s_and_b32     s0, s0, 0x0000ffff                      // 000000000114: 8600FF00 0000FFFF
  s_mul_i32     s0, s0, s8                              // 00000000011C: 92000800
  s_load_dwordx2  s[2:3], s[6:7], 0x00                  // 000000000120: C0060083 00000000
  s_load_dwordx2  s[4:5], s[6:7], 0x30                  // 000000000128: C0060103 00000030
  v_mul_i32_i24  v1, v0, 3                              // 000000000130: D1060001 00010700
  v_mov_b32     v2, 1                                   // 000000000138: 7E040281
  ds_write_b8   v1, v2                                  // 00000000013C: D83C0000 00000201
  v_mov_b32     v2, 2                                   // 000000000144: 7E040282
  ds_write_b8   v1, v2 offset:1                         // 000000000148: D83C0001 00000201
  v_mov_b32     v2, 3                                   // 000000000150: 7E040283
  ds_write_b8   v1, v2 offset:2                         // 000000000154: D83C0002 00000201
  s_waitcnt     lgkmcnt(0)                              // 00000000015C: BF8C007F
  s_add_u32     s0, s0, s2                              // 000000000160: 80000200
  v_add_u32     v0, vcc, s0, v0                         // 000000000164: 32000000
  v_mul_lo_u32  v0, v0, 3                               // 000000000168: D2850000 00010700
  v_ashrrev_i32  v2, 31, v0                             // 000000000170: 2204009F
  v_add_u32     v9, vcc, s4, v0                         // 000000000174: 32120004
  v_mov_b32     v3, s5                                  // 000000000178: 7E060205
  v_addc_u32    v10, vcc, v3, v2, vcc                   // 00000000017C: 38140503
  s_barrier                                             // 000000000180: BF8A0000
  ds_read_u8    v5, v1                                  // 000000000184: D8740000 05000001
  ds_read_u8    v6, v1 offset:1                         // 00000000018C: D8740001 06000001
  ds_read_u8    v1, v1 offset:2                         // 000000000194: D8740002 01000001
  v_add_u32     v3, vcc, v9, 1                          // 00000000019C: D1196A03 00010309
  v_addc_u32    v4, vcc, v10, 0, vcc                    // 0000000001A4: D11C6A04 01A9010A
  v_add_u32     v7, vcc, v9, 2                          // 0000000001AC: D1196A07 00010509
  v_addc_u32    v8, vcc, v10, 0, vcc                    // 0000000001B4: D11C6A08 01A9010A
  s_waitcnt     lgkmcnt(2)                              // 0000000001BC: BF8C027F
  flat_store_byte  v[9:10], v5                          // 0000000001C0: DC600000 00000509
  s_waitcnt     lgkmcnt(2)                              // 0000000001C8: BF8C027F
  flat_store_byte  v[3:4], v6                           // 0000000001CC: DC600000 00000603
  s_waitcnt     lgkmcnt(2)                              // 0000000001D4: BF8C027F
  flat_store_byte  v[7:8], v1                           // 0000000001D8: DC600000 00000107
  s_endpgm
```

this is somewhat different than other GPU results but still 3 instructions per vload or vstore. Maybe its vload and vstore faster.

Only advantage could be the missing loop counter. This may give integer scalar units in hardware more room to compute other things which must be a better case than for loop version.

This is for loop version of same GPU:

```
  s_load_dword  s0, s[4:5], 0x04                        // 000000000100: C0020002 00000004
  s_mov_b32     m0, 0x00010000                          // 000000000108: BEFC00FF 00010000
  s_waitcnt     lgkmcnt(0)                              // 000000000110: BF8C007F
  s_and_b32     s0, s0, 0x0000ffff                      // 000000000114: 8600FF00 0000FFFF
  s_mul_i32     s0, s0, s8                              // 00000000011C: 92000800
  s_load_dwordx2  s[2:3], s[6:7], 0x00                  // 000000000120: C0060083 00000000
  s_waitcnt     lgkmcnt(0)                              // 000000000128: BF8C007F
  s_add_u32     s0, s0, s2                              // 00000000012C: 80000200
  s_load_dwordx2  s[2:3], s[6:7], 0x30                  // 000000000130: C0060083 00000030
  v_mul_i32_i24  v1, v0, 3                              // 000000000138: D1060001 00010700
  v_mov_b32     v2, 1                                   // 000000000140: 7E040281
  v_add_u32     v0, vcc, s0, v0                         // 000000000144: 32000000
  v_mov_b32     v3, 2                                   // 000000000148: 7E060282
  v_mul_lo_u32  v0, v0, 3                               // 00000000014C: D2850000 00010700
  v_mov_b32     v4, 3                                   // 000000000154: 7E080283
  ds_write_b8   v1, v2                                  // 000000000158: D83C0000 00000201
  ds_write_b8   v1, v3 offset:1                         // 000000000160: D83C0001 00000301
  ds_write_b8   v1, v4 offset:2                         // 000000000168: D83C0002 00000401
  v_ashrrev_i32  v2, 31, v0                             // 000000000170: 2204009F
  s_waitcnt     lgkmcnt(0)                              // 000000000174: BF8C007F
  v_add_u32     v9, vcc, s2, v0                         // 000000000178: 32120002
  v_mov_b32     v5, s3                                  // 00000000017C: 7E0A0203
  v_addc_u32    v10, vcc, v5, v2, vcc                   // 000000000180: 38140505
  ds_write_b8   v1, v3 offset:1                         // 000000000184: D83C0001 00000301
  ds_write_b8   v1, v4 offset:2                         // 00000000018C: D83C0002 00000401
  s_waitcnt     lgkmcnt(0)                              // 000000000194: BF8C007F
  s_barrier                                             // 000000000198: BF8A0000
  ds_read_u8    v5, v1                                  // 00000000019C: D8740000 05000001
  ds_read_u8    v6, v1 offset:1                         // 0000000001A4: D8740001 06000001
  ds_read_u8    v1, v1 offset:2                         // 0000000001AC: D8740002 01000001
  v_add_u32     v3, vcc, v9, 1                          // 0000000001B4: D1196A03 00010309
  v_addc_u32    v4, vcc, v10, 0, vcc                    // 0000000001BC: D11C6A04 01A9010A
  v_add_u32     v7, vcc, v9, 2                          // 0000000001C4: D1196A07 00010509
  v_addc_u32    v8, vcc, v10, 0, vcc                    // 0000000001CC: D11C6A08 01A9010A
  s_waitcnt     lgkmcnt(2)                              // 0000000001D4: BF8C027F
  flat_store_byte  v[9:10], v5                          // 0000000001D8: DC600000 00000509
  s_waitcnt     lgkmcnt(2)                              // 0000000001E0: BF8C027F
  flat_store_byte  v[3:4], v6                           // 0000000001E4: DC600000 00000603
  s_waitcnt     lgkmcnt(2)                              // 0000000001EC: BF8C027F
  flat_store_byte  v[7:8], v1                           // 0000000001F0: DC600000 00000107
  s_endpgm
```

I couldn't find loop counter related instruction here, probably compiler already recognizes the pattern in both vloadn and loop versions and produces same machine code. But this is just ISA, I can't say whats really happening in cores. Maybe VLIW gains more, CPU gains even more but newest GPUs may not much.

Comment: Applying this to my kernel does not work. It compiles, however, it crashes with a segmentation fault at runtime. I presume the problem is that your solution writes to a local array while i need to write to a local buffer?

Comment: if vector4 version doesn't work too, then it must be the "buffer" versus "array" issue.

Comment: Thanks. Since the size of my local buffer is a multiple of 3 i allocated it one bigger, such that i could do vload4 from it without accessing it out of bounds. However, this still crashes, hence, it must have to do with the buffer issue.

Comment: You are giving NULL in clSetKernelArg function aren't you?

Comment: I'm using pyOpenCL so i don't have to do that. I pass the allocated local memory to the corresponding argument of my kernel.

Comment: Can you put those py codes relevant to "binding arrays to kernels" part?

Comment: Does py have null equivalent to put in Last parameter

Comment: I found in the documentation that pyOpenCL has a `set_arg` function, it states: `None: This may be passed for __global memory references to pass a NULL pointer to the kernel.`

Comment: Local buffer May not be used for output so you May give its size but not an Object so it is used as local array with dynamic size. You need a global array for output maybe as a second parameter also isnt there a vector option why scalar here

Comment: Ok, i need to clarify things a bit. I am writing a convolution algorithm. Hence, each work item of a work group first copies his needed pixels to the local memory buffer. Then i use a barrier, and afterwards i perform my convolution using this local buffer. Hence, i am using the local buffer to share data between my work items of a workgroup and not as an output buffer. Regarding the vectorization, i originally had local memory as an uchar4 buffer, but since i need only 3 bytes that wastes 1 byte, which i cannot afford (and openCL has no vectors of length 3..)

Comment: `applyKernel.set_scalar_arg_dtypes([None]) # None because it is a buffer` maybe here needs to be a specific thing for local

Answer (score 0):

The pattern in your kernel is an obvious candidate for a compiler to optimise code for, specially since the upper limit of the loop is defined at constant value. 
The function **async_work_group_copy** is only to copy between *local* and *global* memory, not for *private*. Its main purpose is to hide latency (i.e. do other things while the memory operation is performed). Calling the "async" functions in the kernel and then immediately waiting will probably be as slow as without the function.